# Merits and demerits of convolutional and linear block codes

Tags: communication-protocols, error-correcting-codes

Continuing on from my previous [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/convolutional-and-linear-block-codes/53771#53771)...

Both convolution and linear block codes can be used for error correction. The main benefits I gathered from using convolutional codes is that, it's easy to implement and does better (than linear codes) in cases where you have higher error probability rates and noisy channels. Information bits are spread along the sequence. Lastly, these codes have memory.

However, linear block codes, especially the newer ones such as polar code, can actually achieve the channel capacity. And, in block codes, information bits are followed by parity bits and code information in blocks. Lastly, they are memory less.

Given this, what other merits and demerits are there to using convolutional or linear block codes?

I ask this because I have a system which has low processing power and high error rate, caused by mostly burst errors.  What would be the better coding to use and why? It is also to be noted that this error rate is very erratic. A number of factors affect the error rate: time the RF modules are turned on, noise, temperature, obstacles, etc. I tried a Reed-Solomon code, but it still doesn't do the job.